# Count subtests in Python unittests separately

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, parameterized-unit-test

Since version 3.4, Python [supports a simple subtest syntax when writing unittests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests). A simple example could look like this:

```
import unittest

class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_successful(self):
        """A test with subtests that will all succeed."""
        for i in range(0, 6):
            with self.subTest(i=i):
                self.assertEqual(i, i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When running the tests, the output will be

```
python3 test_foo.py --verbose
test_successful (__main__.NumbersTest)
A test with subtests that will all succeed. ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

However, in my real world use cases, the subtests will depend on a more complex iterable and check something which is very different for each subtest. Consequently, I would rather have each subtest counted and listed as a separated test case in the output (`Ran 6 tests in ...` in this example) to get the full picture.

Is this somehow possible with the plain `unittest` module in Python? [The nose test generator feature](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators) would output each test separately but I would like to stay compatible with the standard library if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass `unittest.TestResult`:

```
class NumbersTestResult(unittest.TestResult):
    def addSubTest(self, test, subtest, outcome):
        # handle failures calling base class
        super(NumbersTestResult, self).addSubTest(test, subtest, outcome)
        # add to total number of tests run
        self.testsRun += 1
```

Then in `NumbersTest` override the `run` function:

```
def run(self, test_result=None):
    return super(NumbersTest, self).run(NumbersTestResult())
```

Sorry I cannot test this in a fully working environment right now, but this should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Using python 3.5.2, themiurge's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45008317/602721) didn't work out-of-the-box for me but a little tweaking got it to do what I wanted.

I had to specifically get the test runner to use this new class as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main(testRunner=unittest.TextTestRunner(resultclass=NumbersTestResult))
```

However this didn't print the details of the test failures to the console as in the default case. To restore this behaviour I had to change the class `NumbersTestResult` inherited from to `unittest.TextTestResult`.

```
class NumbersTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):
    def addSubTest(self, test, subtest, outcome):
        # handle failures calling base class
        super(NumbersTestResult, self).addSubTest(test, subtest, outcome)
        # add to total number of tests run
        self.testsRun += 1
```